# Mocking next/head does not seem to do anything

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, next.js

I have a Seo component that uses the next/head component. I would like to test this Seo component, but mocking next/head seems to do nothing at all. Am I doing something wrong?

```js
import TestRenderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import Seo from '../Seo';

jest.mock(
  "next/head",
  () => function Head({ children }) {
    return children;
  },
);

it('should display seo', () => {
  const render = TestRenderer.create(
    <Seo />,
  );
  expect(render.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

```js
import Head from "next/head";

function Seo() {
  return (
    <Head>
      <title>Title SEO</title>
    </Head>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by _"mocking next/head seems to do nothing at all"_? The snapshot seems to have what the `Seo` component renders. What were you expecting it to do?

Comment: @juliomalves since the Head component injects its content into the document.head, nothing shows in the template. That's why I'm attempting to replace the Head component so that it simply displays its content. That's what I mean by "mocking it". But it does not work, the snapshot stays empty.

Comment: I understand. Using your code above, the mocking works for me and I can see `<title>Title SEO</title>` in the snapshot.

Comment: The result of my snapshot is : `exports['should display seo 1'] = 'null';` I'm using `"jest": "^27.4.7"` and `"next": "latest"` (as of this date). I'm testing on fresh project. Do you have any idea? I don't understand.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me (remove typescript if just using js)

```
jest.mock('next/head', () => {
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    default: ({ children }: { children: Array<React.ReactElement> }) => {
      return <>{children}</>;
    },
  };
});
```

Comment: It does not work, can you please tell me the versions of next and jest that you are using ?

Comment: `"next": "12.0.10"`
`"jest": "^27.4.7"`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the test should be delayed to wait for the DOM manipulation to end. Also `document.head` might be needed to be provided as a `container`.

```
it('should display seo', async () => {
  const render = TestRenderer.create(
    <Seo />, {container: document.head}
  );
  await waitFor(() => {
    expect(render.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```